# Is it true that uploading file always requires multipart/form-data?

Tags: rest, http, go, upload, form-data

I am working on a rest endpoint which should get the request body stream and consume it. I tried to get the body of request (Content-Type as text/csv or application/octet-stream) and read from it using buffer.

```
reader := r.Body.(io.Reader)
writer := bufio.NewWriter(outputFile) // we write to

for {
    buffer := make([]byte, 4000)
    numBytes, err := reader.Read(buffer)
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        return
    }
    if read > 0 {
        writer.Write(buffer[0:numBytes])
    } else {
        break
    }
}
writer.Flush();
```

Above is my golang code. I got nothing from the request.Body. However, if I use multipart/form-data I can get the data from the parts. Does http always require form-data for uploading??

Comment: The code in the question does not handle the case where Read returns numBytes > 0 and err == io.EOF.  I suggest replacing all of the code with  `io.Copy(outputFile, r.Body)`.

Comment: The contents of a file can be uploaded without using multipart/form-data. Print r.Header to confirm that the content type is what you expect. Also, check to see if the content length is greater than zero.  Also, show the complete request handler and note of you are using "middleware".

Comment: @MellowMarmot, Thanks a lot! Content-Type is text/csv when I uploaded a csv file. I also tried plain text file. In the response I get the same content-type as what i set in the request. What am I missing? my csv file can be very larget, so I wanna handle it with buffer reader.

Comment: Are you copying the request body to the response?